# Не отображается картинка из папки static/images при запуске Spring App

Tags: java, spring, mvc, thymeleaf

Сегодня стал изучать Spring по книге Spring in action . В заключение первой главы ,  сделано простое очень MVC приложение в котором должно отображаться приветствия и картинка , загрузил картинку как было сказано в static/images  но при запуске в веб браузер вышла выходит что у меня в thymeleaf без скриншота , он просто пустой , по разному пытался менять пути к файлу , но не помогает , картинка не подгружается на сервер , привык исправлять каждую деталь , прикладываю код и скрин ответа от сервера.

Скрин ответа от сервера :
[Ответ от сервера](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOpOp.jpg)
...

Класс запуска :

```
package tacos;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TacoCloudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TacoCloudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Класс контроллера

```
package tacos;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.html";
    }
}
```

Шаблон html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to...</h1>
    <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот структура всего Eclipse

[Структура](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F5X8.jpg)

Comment: Попробуйте другой браузер или режим "инкогнито", вроде все нормально у вас

Comment: К сожалению не помогло , и так головняк с пониманием всего Spring на сегодняшний день и что делает мой код , так и картинку не хочет встраивать в браузер...

Comment: return "home.html"; измените на return "home";

Comment: И так тоже не хочет , менял изображения , вставлял разные форматы, менял path , просто не в каком из браузеров не хочет , я не понимаю в чем может заключаться это ...

Comment: Вижу `target` у вас пустой, в свзяи с чем вопрос - вы проект запускали или просто смотрели html через  браузер?

Comment: Запускал и не работало , по одному из здешних ответов поменял в шаблоне thymeleaf , на обычный html <img> заработало. Вопрос решен!

Answer (score 2):

если ресурс лежит в папке static, то он доступен из корня сайта
не надо просить thymeleaf найти ресурс поменяйте на

```html
<img src="/images/TacoCloud.png"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо , действительно помогло , из корня сайта имеется введу , из этого каталога где лежит весь проект?

Comment: Корень - это я говорю про базовый url, в данном случае это http://localhost:8080/ . th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}" такая запись позволяет не заботиться о том с каким контекстом запускается приложение, thymeleaf будет искать в classpath в папке resources папку images и автоматически дополнит путь к ресурсу соответствующим контекстом. Это нужно например если вы собираете WAR файл с именем myapp и кладете его в Tomcat, то после запуска приложения в коде уже будет <img src="/myapp/images/TacoCloud.png"/>

Answer (score 0):

Изначально проект создавал без зависимостей, которые далее скопировал в pom. Пробовал все предложенные варианты, не помогло. Получилось решить проблему созданием нового проекта через https://start.spring.io/, и добавлением в проект сразу трех зависимостей "Spring Boot DevTools", "Thymeleaf", "Spring Web". Далее скопировал всё из src старого проекта и всё отобразилось корректно. Но понять с чем связано не смог.